# When a given set of primes of height 1 is a set associated primes of an element

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $R$ be a Noetherian local ring of dimension $\geq 3$ and $\{p_1,\ldots , p_n\}$ be a collection of prime ideals of height $1$. Does there exist an element $x\in R$ such that $Ass(R/xR)=\{p_1,\ldots , p_n\}$.

Comment: No. Try the case of a Dedekind domain and $n=1$.

Comment: @Mohan I have edited the question. Can we say anything if R is a domain or R has no embedded associated primes with dimension>=3?

Comment: If you have an example in dimension $n$, taking polynomial ring over it, you get an example in dimension $n+1$.